# How to create the empty package in Java?

Tags: java, compilation, package

I have the following directory structure:

```
A.java
a
└── A.java
```

A.java:

```
import a.*;

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Human");
    }
}
```

a/A.java:

```
package a;
public class A {}
```

And it compiles and runs:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
Hello Human
```

But when I remove `a/A.java` (but keep the folder `a`), I can no longer compile it:

```
$ rm a/A.java 
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:1: package a does not exist
import a.*;
^
1 error
```

Why?

Comment: remove that import statement and it will compile

Comment: you are importing a package that isn't declared (a directory by itself isn't automatically a package)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might say that the package `a` is not *observable*:

> A package is observable if and only if either:
>
> - A compilation unit containing a declaration of the package is observable (§7.3).
> - A subpackage of the package is observable.

source: [Observability of a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.3)

Answer (score 3):

This is your problem right here:

import a.*;

It's looking for something that doesn't exist, since that package is no longer there.

Remove that line from A.java and it should work fine.

The reason it can't find the package is because there is no compilable classes within the folder, and so it isn't recognised as a java package.

One option for creating an empty package, if you do need one, would be to specify a package-info.java file, which is generally used as a javadoc for packages.

Comment: I think he understands that.  I think he wants to know why he has to do that **given that the 'a' folder still exists**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @StephenC, I've updated my answer a bit so that it's more in the spirit of the question.